# My webpage shown on mobile device has changed and squeezed (difference from desktop browser)

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

I have setup the website .It should show as the css setting .
The page works when I turn around the IPad device .

However , for the smaller screen size device ,like 5.5 inch smart phone .

The webpage structure has been totally changed and squeezed  .

I have added the below code in the HTML .But it doesn't work .

**Any convenient and simple way to make the page shown with mobile device ,as same as the page shown using computer browser ?**

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">



    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
    ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
```

Computer version:
[image]

Mobile version:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve issue this by using Javascript to force the view to be as a desktop view.

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: Sure I will prepare it and share it with you. @Vito  also if you can share a demo file with us we might fix it using CSS

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to use breakpoints.  Basically, it works like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    /* Fill here with CSS styling */
}
```

`@media` is used to define different styling rules for different devices or screen widths.  Basically, it tells the browser to get ready to set a breakpoint.

`screen` is the part that tells the browser what kind of media will be changing.

`(min-width: 500px)` is the actual breakpoint.  Any device that has a screen width of 500 pixels and up will have those styling rules applied to them.  An alternative would be to use `max-width`, which does the opposite.

Comment: /* Fill here with CSS styling */ = fill all css styling?

Comment: @Vito: Fill with CSS styling that will apply to that screen size.  You can set up more breakpoints to have different styling for larger/smaller screen sizes.